# Different solutions for same integral when using different variables

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, variable-definitions

Consider the following integral:

$$I := \int_1^2 \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2-x) (x-1)}} \, dx.$$

The solution of this integral is $I = \pi $.

I typed this integral into Mathematica in a more general form:

```
Integrate[1/Sqrt[(a - x)*(x - b)], {x, b, a}]
```

But the output of this is $0$.

Using different variables:

```
Integrate[1/Sqrt[(x1 - x)*(x - x2)], {x, x2, x1}]
```

gives the right solution $\pi$.

I don't see the difference between my two inputs. I also used `ClearAll[a, b, x1, x2]` before evaluating.

Comment: I am using Wolfram Mathematica 10.2

Comment: in ver 11.2 (macOS 10.13.2) `ConditionalExpression[\[Pi], a >= b]` assuming $a,b\in \mathcal{R}$

Answer (score 1):

Integrate[1/Sqrt[(a - x)*(x - b)], {x, b, a}, Assumptions -> a > b]